# Optimizing the shopping cart database calls

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Shopping Cart items are grouped and shown as links. For instance, a user has got a group of "T-shirts". When he clicks that link ("T-shirts") a bootstrap modal window pops up with all the t-shirts listed as links on the right and all the details (picture, size, price, etc) about the selected (first on the list) t-shirt are shown on the left.

Now, when a user clicks on any other link (inside that modal window) to see the details of a different t-shirt a request to the database is made. Average user can make over 100 request in a matter of minutes, checking his stuff and retrieving the same data over and over, which looks as a waste of resources to me.

My question is - how do I go about optimizing this process?
Can I load all the data about the chosen group and just pass it to the modal window every time user clicks on a different item?
If so, where do I store this data?

As far as I understand session variables still require some server side work which I would like to avoid. 
Are cookies a way to go in this scenario? Or is it an overkill and I shouldn't be bothered at all?

Thanks

Comment: You say _"checking his stuff and retrieving the same data over and over, which looks as a waste of resources to me."_ but is it **actually** a waste of resources? Have you measured the performance of getting this data? Is it a strain on your server? Is your database overloaded with queries? Unless you can say 'yes' to all these then you are optimising prematurely.

Comment: If the data is not per user, then it doesn't belong in the session. The application itself can store data and you can use Cache objects to handle this if the data is the same for everyone. Or if you want, you can send it all to the browser, depending on the amount. But as @Tony said, if you don't have a problem now, don't spend your time optimizing it now.

Comment: @Tony -  Right, this is definitely a premature optimization, since this is my first real world project that will go live. No clue whether it's needed or not(the optimization, not the project ^^ )..

"Have you measured the performance of getting this data?" - the only way I know is the execution time in LINQpad (~00:00.050) pretty much for all of my queries.
"Is your database overloaded with queries?" - How do I check this on a shared hosting?

@ Sami - The IS the per user data, since we're talking about a regular private shopping cart. "send it all to the browser" - could you please clarify?

Comment: Think of persisting already requested data (client side, and/or application cache, as appropriate), so _at least_ you don't have to make a db call for the _same_ data within some lifetime you define...Hth

Comment: @tereško are you on an editing spree once again? The entire frontpage is filled with your `asp.net` + `model-view-controller` to `asp.net-mvc` edits. Please consider editing and voting on the posts you edit and not spamming the entire frontpage.

Comment: @CodeCaster they end up in a frontpage?! WHY?

Comment: @tereško my entire frontpage (http://stackoverflow.com) is filled with questions you just edited the past few hours.

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't see a single one of my edits there. Maybe the SO cache soiled itself. **Edit:** could it be per-chance, that you have asp.net-mvc in your favorite tags?